# Values of some "natural" sums over multiindices with a given absolut value

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, summation

I'd like to know if there is a nice closed expression in terms of $j$ and $k$ of the sum
$$
S_{j,k}:=\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in \mathbb{N}^k_0:\\i_1+\cdots+i_k=j}\frac{1}{i_1!\cdots i_k!}.
$$
Furthermore, given $m\in \{0,\ldots,k\}$, I am interested in a closed expression for the values $$
S^m_{j,k}:=\sum_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)\in \mathbb{N}^k_0:\\i_1+\cdots+i_k=j,\\
m\text{ of  the numbers } \\i_1,\ldots,i_k \text{ are odd} }\frac{1}{i_1!\cdots i_k!},
$$
but I guess that this is hopeless. In both cases, I am happy to assume that $j$ and $k$ are even.

Comment: $S_{j,k}=k^j/j!$, by the multinomial theorem: $k^j=(1+1+\dots+1)^j=\sum \frac{j!}{i_1!\cdots i_k!}$.

Comment: For $S^m_{j,k}$, do you mean _exactly_ $m$ of the numbers are odd, so the rest are even? Or do you mean that _at least_ $m$ of them are odd?

Comment: I mean that exactly $m$ are odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^x = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$, but then: $e^x\cdot e^x...\cdot e^x = e^{kx} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n\cdot x^n}{n!}$ and we see that $S_{j, k} = \frac{k^j}{j!}$, because left hand side is a product of $k$ series and the coefficient before $x^j$ is what we need.

edit: For the second one: see comments by @MikeErnest below.

Comment: You last sentence is not correct. The coefficient of $x^j$ in $(\sinh(x))^me^{x(k-m)}$ is equal to $\sum \frac1{i_1!\dots i_k!}$, where the sum ranges over $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ such that $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_m$ are odd. This is not equivalent to saying "$m$ of the numbers $i_1,\dots,i_k$ are odd."

Comment: @MikeEarnest i agree, edited.

Comment: I think there is still a problem. $\binom{k}m \sinh^m x \cosh^{k-m} x$ gives you a summation over all vectors with _exactly_ $m$ odd numbers. If you wanted to count summations with _at least_ $m$ odd numbers, you could not simply use $\binom{k}m\sinh^m xe^{(k-m)x}$, because vectors with more than $m$ ones would be over-counted. You instead need $\sum_{h=m}^k \binom{k}h \sinh^h x\cosh^{k-h} x$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest And you are again correct...